# Tensorflow division evaluates to infinity

Tags: python, tensorflow, division

i am new in Tensorflow, so sorry for obvious mistakes.

I try to make a division wich evaluates to inf. The following line produces the problem :

```
style_loss1_1 = tf.div(tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(tensor_gen_gram1_1 - tensor_style_gram1_1, 2)),
                       tf.mul(tf.mul(4.0, 2517630976.0), 9.0))
```

I know that the i only multiply numbers, but if this works, i want to replace them by Tensorflow variables. So i need this multiplication.
The thing which makes me crazy is, that when i change this line to this one :

```
style_loss1_1 = tf.div(tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(tensor_gen_gram1_1 - tensor_style_gram1_1, 2)),
                       1.0)
```

everything works fine and i get the result : 7.41678e+19

I would be thankful for any help :)

Comment: Could you provide the values of `tensor_gen_gram1_1` and `tensor_style...` to make the snippet reproducible without having to type more code?

Comment: What is your github project?

Comment: Cause these both tensors has the shape (224,224,64), i wrote them to files and added them to the github project. [link](https://github.com/k-moller/DLVD_Project/blob/master/StyleTransfer/matrixes.zip). There you will also find the StryleTransfer.py file which includes the above code at line 152.

Comment: Have you tried splitting the operation into parts and seeing intermediate values? For example, just the value of reduce sum and the multiplication?

Comment: Yes, I already tried this, but to give you some results i retried and i got for the reduce_sum part infinity. The last time i had a real number, so i think i did a mistake the last time. Then i made a tf.cas(tf.reduce_sum(...), tf.float64) and i got a result. So i could solve my problem. The division works perfectly now :) Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You are welcome, could you write an answer for this?